# How to see disk space history - Nagios Core

Tags: nagios

I stood up Nagios Core for my employer and it's working out great out of the box. I'm monitoring most of our drives, services and windows servers using check_nt.

I'm just trying to see the disk space history for a certain drive. I know that if you go to the availability report, you can see changes in disk space usage, but I'm hoping to get it in a more usable format - such as a CSV or a graph. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, It's definitely possible. I use something called PNP4Nagios to generate graphs that display all history but there are other tools with loads of documentation available online.

Another option is NagiosGraph (or a combination of Graphite and Grafana if you're feeling brave).

PNP4Nagios - http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/install

NagiosGraph - http://www.linuxfunda.com/2013/04/02/steps-to-configure-nagiosgraph-with-nagios-core/

Drop me a message if you're having troubles with any of the above.